# How does Depot's cart retain its line items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Capturing an Order chapter in Agile Wed Development with Rails uses the following code:

```
# orders_controller.rb
def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
    if @order.save
      Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
      session[:cart_id] = nil
      redirect_to store_url
    else
      @cart = current_cart
      render 'new'
    end
end

  # order.rb
  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
  end
```

How does the cart retain its line items when there's a validation error? The `add_line_items_from_cart` runs before we know whether the order is valid or not. It associates the line items with the order, then sets the `item.cart_id` to nil:

```
item.cart_id = nil
self.line_items << item # self is an instance of `Order`.
```

When I submit an empty form then view the cart, all the line items are still there. How is this possible? What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cart is only destroyed when the order is saved. So I guess it will never lose the items. What happens is when you create the order it probably destroy the current cart and the it creates a new one.

Comment: I understand that. But the association is `LineItem belongs_to :cart`. When we're looping over line items and setting `cart_id` to `nil`, it makes no difference wether the cart is destroyed--`line_item.cart_id` is now `nil`. I suspect it's to do with Rails rolling back the transaction when `@order.save` returns `false`, but I'm yet to verify this. Still looking into it.

Comment: Nop, actually what happens is that you changed the cart_id but if it's not valid it does not save to the database. So it won't save the line_items in the database. Makes sense?

Comment: I'm not saving the line item, though. `item.cart_id = nil` then `self.line_items << item`, where `self` is an instance of order... so the line_item validation does not even come into play. It's the order I'm trying to save, which fails, but after we change the cart_id in the line items.

Comment: Yes, but those changes will only happen when you save them to the database. And that happens when you save the Order because items are related to it. So when the order gets saved, items will also be saved. If the order is not valid, it wont save the order and so it wont save the changes to items.

Comment: Maybe if you look into the console you see those SQL UPDATEs to lines when order gets saved.